# how to create bootable usb stick for mac on ubuntu?

Tags: usb

I would like to make a bootable usb on Ubuntu to boot on mac. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use these instructions. Worked for me on a mid-2012 MBP

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder containing the img in the terminal

use dd if=filename.img of=/dev/sda (check your path before pressing return) bs=1M

and be careful with that "of part" its usually  sda but check it with  `sudo fdisk -l`  cause any wrong name and you'll be destroying the entire partition